# kudu custom deployment fails for asp.net core webapp

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.1, kudu

I use pretty much standard custom kudu deployment script for asp.net core web app for external git deployment.
I managed to run the script mostly successfully, through mingling with SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT and .cmd files encoding. My deployment scripts look as follows:

.deployment

```
[config]
command = deploy.cmd
```

deploy.cmd

```
@echo off
IF "%WEBSITE_SITE_TYPE%" == "<project_name>" (
    .\<project folder>\Properties\deploy.cmd
    goto end
)

echo Unknown WEBSITE_SITE_TYPE: "%WEBSITE_SITE_TYPE%". Expected one of the "<project name>"

:end
exit /b
```

`.\<project folder>\Properties\deploy.cmd` - regular asp.net core deploy.cmd script, updated for proper folder structure.

The WEBSITE_SITE_TYPE is a custom environment variable I added to the web app.
All these scripts saved with utf-8 without BOM encoding.

But even though the scripts look like runs successfully, the final state of the deployment process is Failed.

When looking into the kudu deployment log last few lines of the log look as follows:

```
...
2018-10-14T20:50:51.0660695Z,Copying file: 'wwwroot\runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js',,0
2018-10-14T20:50:51.0660695Z,Copying file: 'wwwroot\styles.8ef9ef86d2a54ed3748c.css',,0
2018-10-14T20:50:51.0816988Z,Deleting app_offline.htm,,0
2018-10-14T20:50:51.0816988Z,Finished successfully.,,0
2018-10-14T20:50:51.1129431Z,\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\78.11002.3584\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd deploy.cmd,,2
```

Apparently the last line returns error code 2 and it might cause the script status to fail. But what does it mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not sure it matters, but I don't think you need the `exit /b` at the end. Also, I think you need to use `call` to call the other batch file. And to help isolate, you should try reducing both of your `deploy.cmd` to no-op scripts that just have echo lines, to get more other things out of the equation.

Comment: Indeed, the problem was with missing `call` statements for the project build.cmd scripts. Thank you @david-ebbo

Comment: @DavidEbbo please provide your comment as an answer so that the OP will accept the answer and it could help other members too.Thanks